# Basic Software configuration in Autosar Development

Tags: autosar

In the power-on state, which component from a basic software stack will be initialized with respect to AUTOSAR? or How the BSW stack will be  initialized.

Any one Suggest me?

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, EcuM will be initialized first and will enter its STARTUP state. Then EcuM will initialize basic software, including drivers, in several different groups, called init blocks. EcuM will then starting the OS and, after that, also start and initialize the BSW Mode Manager (BswM), and start the scheduler. From that point on, mode machines are operational, meaning that the next steps can depend on the BswM configuration for the particular ECU.

For details, refer to the 'Specification of ECU State Manager' in Autosar, in particular section 7.3 (in Autosar version 4.3.1).

Comment: I am still learning but from what I understand, I think that it's worth mentioning these steps: 1. Startup Code(uC dependent), 2. MCU Driver(to init clock, PLL, RAM sections), 3. EcuM, 4. BswM.

Answer (score -1):

1. `ECUm`
2. `Bswm`
3. `Schm`
4. `comM`

Further elements depend on the configuration.